# Initialize an int array with some zeros

Tags: c, arrays

i made a simple sorting program in which i initialized array like below.

```
int a[]={9,4,7,8,5,2,6,1,0,3};
```

but my sorting function sorts array a[0] to a[7] and treats 0 like '\0' and stops. if i put 0 at some other place it is sorting just up to 0 and ignores rest of the array. Is C is treating 0 and '\0' same here?

My Bubble Sort Program is as below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
int a[]={9,4,7,8,5,2,6,1,0,3};

void bubble_sort(int *a);
void print(int *a);

bubble_sort(a);

print(a);

getch();

return 0;
}

void bubble_sort(int *a)
{
int i=0,j,t,n;
for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
{
    n=0;
    for(j=1;a[j]!='\0';j++)
    {
        if(a[j-1]>a[j])
        {
            t=a[j-1];
            a[j-1]=a[j];
            a[j]=t;
            n++;
        }
    }
    if(n==0)
    {
         break;
    }
}
}

void print(int a[])
{
int i=0;

for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
{
    printf("%d ",a[i]);
}

printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I wonder whether its a good idea to write function prototypes inside main function...

Comment: pass the length of the array to ``bubble_sort``. no guarantee array will end in `\0' (=0).

Comment: "Is C is treating 0 and '\0' same here?" -- By definition. '\0' only *conventionally* signals the end of an array of **`char`** ... it isn't some sort of generic end-of-array sentinel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'\0'` is `0` by definition. You need to pass the length of your array to your sorting function, or else choose a different integer value as a terminator and make sure you never use that value for anything else.

Answer (score 4):

The character `'\0'` is exactly equal to 0.  You will want to pass an array length into your sorting algorithm, then use that.

Comment: Huh, beaten by 50 seconds, with (almost) exactly the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Is C is treating 0 and '\0' same here?

Yes. It's because both are zero. As others mentioned,or you pass the length of your array to function or use chose another delimiter for your array where you need to ensure that it will not contains in your array.

EDIT: @Jim Balter,thanks for clarification.

Comment: That `'\0' == 0` doesn't have anything to do with the fact that numbers beginning with 0 are in octal, and there is no `\O` notation in C.

Comment: @JimBalter: I mean `\0`,sorry.

Comment: @Jim Balter: What if C handle `0` as decimal base will 0 == `\0` be true?

Comment: Of course it would; 0 is 0 in any base. `'\0'` is a char constant with value 0, and char constants in C (not C++) have type `int`, so it not only equals 0 but it has the same type.

Comment: Your edit doesn't help. '\0' == 0 == 0x0 == '\x00' == 99 - 99 ... the base is irrelevant. What is relevant is that they all have the same value -- zero.

Answer (score 2):

**'\0' is NULL character**.ASCII code of NULL Character is 0.

```
a[i]!='\0' is equivalent to a[i]!=0
```

since '\0' is type casted to its ASCII value(Integer).

Thus the loop stops when ever current element is zero.

In order to **fix** it,pass an extra argument : **array size**

```
bubble_sort(a,sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));
print(a,sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));
```

Change the **bubble_sort** function to:

```
void bubble_sort(int *a,int sz)
{
    int i=0,j,t,n;
    for(i=0;i<sz;i++)
    {
        n=0;
        for(j=1;j<sz;j++)
        {
        ...................................
```

Change the **print** function to:

```
void print(int a[],int sz)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<sz;i++)
    {
                 .......................
```

Please note:

in C++ it is nearly impossible to calculate the size of  array from decaying pointer(int *a or int a[]).
Therefore, always an extra argument : **size of array** is passed along with array.

However, whenever character array is passed to a function, simply iterating the array until NULL character is encountered works as in  C/C++, a string of characters is stored in successive elements of a character array and terminated by the NULL character.